# PHP mysql separate the resultset by variety

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

My Query:

```
SELECT type, variety, quantity, total, purchase_invoice_number, bill_number, sale_date, wholesale_invoice_number, date(entered_date) as entered_date 
FROM purchase_retailsales_wholesales 
WHERE date(entered_date) BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-01-22' AND item_code = '1-KHADHI' 
ORDER BY variety, entered_date
```

Result:

[image]
[image]

What I want is, at the end of each variety (see marked area in image) I want a page break` or special text called "End of Variety". How can I achieve it? Through PHP or mysql?

Comment: mysql group by will solve this prob...

Comment: @user1844933, i want all varieties, for eg i want 10KA127*183 for 4 times, if i give group by it comes only one time, i want a seperation when variety changes thats it.

Comment: This is purely a display issue, right? If so, it should be solved in PHP. GROUP BY will do nothing for you here.

Answer (score 1):

When you echo the rows store the variety value in a variable. For each row then check if the variety is the same as the previous one, if not then echo a divider or text. Of course you'll have to skip this check for the first row.